# Cannot change md_bg_color in kivy file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, theming

I cannot change background color of my MDToolbar. When i set primary_palette for my ThemeManager(), the value actually changes(i checked it with print() from my .kv file), but the color of toolbar doesn't. Could anyone help me?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Purple"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

And here is the code from .kv file:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDToolbar:
        title: "This is an MDToolBar"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: print(x)], ['bookmark', lambda x: print(app.theme_cls.primary_color)]]
        right_action_items: [['lumx', lambda x: print('HELLO!') if True else print("No")]]
    Button:
        text: "A button"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the line self.theme_cls = ThemeManager() in the new version of kivymd you don't need to add that anymore

Comment: Ok, thank you. But i have found another solution: just to set return Builder.load_file(<nameOf.KvFile>) in build() method instead of connecting this .kv file by convention. Anyway, thanks!